# how do i copy a file only on click of a button?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, copying

i had posted a previous question a bit same like this one and it got solved but i now am facing a new problem.i want to duplicate a file with the data inside it when the user clicks a button. In my previous question i figured out how to copy a file and paste it but now what happened is that the second i run my program it duplicates my file, and it doesn't even paste the data into the new file, it just creates the new file with the name i specified, but i want it to happen like when the user clicks a button then the file should be duplicated and the data should be inside it. Here is the code i used:

```
from tkinter import  *


root=Tk()


def duplicatefunction():
    f=open("prototype.txt","r")
    g=open("copy.txt","w")


button1=Button(text="duplicate file", command=duplicatefunction())
button1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

so what did i do wrong and how to fix it to copy the data in the files???

Answer (score 1):

You should not include the `()` in the command argument in your Button. So write

```
button1 = Button(text="duplicate file", command=duplicatefunction)
```

The duplicate function that you have doesn't do anything but opening 2 files. One for reading and one for writing, but you're not actually reading or writing anything.

If you want to create a copy, you can use the `copy2()` function from the `shutil` library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

In that case the duplicate function could look like:

```
def duplicatefunction():
    shutil.copy2('prototype.txt', 'copy.txt')
```

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH IT WORKED, I WAS STARING AT MY COMPUTER SINCE 5 HRS THINKING WHT TO DO BUT NOW AT LAST IT WORKED!!!!!!!

Comment: hey but when i copy it, there's no data inside the file

Comment: odd but pls tell wht to do??

Comment: That is odd... is there data in the original file that you try to copy?

Comment: yes there was data inside original file

Comment: what are you using for the duplicatefunction now? Can you paste it here?

Comment: ok this is the code i m currently using:

Comment: from tkinter import  *


root=Tk()

#specifying the function going to be assigned to the button
def duplicatefunction():
    f=open("prototype.txt","r")
    g=open("copy.txt","w+")

    a=f.read()

    g.write(a)

button1=Button(text="duplicate file", command=duplicatefunction)
button1.pack()


root.mainloop()

Comment: it is not clear but the code is right

Comment: Well not really... you're opening files but not closing them, so you might want to use context managers in this case. Also not sure why you would re-invent a copy function that exists and is part of Python's standard library? And hence very well tested by a large community.

Comment: anyways don't worry @robbo now the file is working and i got really excited and created tons of duplicates, i'll go delete them now 